# unable to see Number of comments in SP2010 Blog

Tags: 2010, blog

i am not sure if anyone has ran into a problem like this before, on our Blog Page the number of comments are missing, although the link "Comment(s)" is visible but without the count of comments on the post.

i dont have access to server as well as dont have SP Designer, i guess it has something to do with the Lookup column, but i cannot even check the properties of these Lookup column as these are default columns created by SP 2010 Blog Template, is there any other way to check or edit the column attributes of "Number of comments" or to relink it.

on the Blog page under every blog, next to the *Permanent Link* and *Post Link* icon it shows the link as "***Comment(s)"*** but no number of comments or count of comments.

any ideas??? how to display number of comments?
Thanks in advance
Server sap

Answer (score 1):

The field for displaying *number of comments* is declared in [List Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543477.aspx) for Blog list

```
<Field Name="NumComments" 
       Type="Lookup" 
       DisplayName="$Resources:posts_schema_blgfld_numcomments;" 
       CountRelated="TRUE" 
       List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/$Resources:core,blogcomments_Folder;" 
       ShowField="PostTitle" 
       ID="{e136aa19-e8d1-1b3c-a32c-aba3e58a971b}" 
       Sealed="TRUE" 
       SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" 
       StaticName="NumComments">
</Field>
```

where
the source list (`List` attribute) for [Lookup field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookup.aspx) is Comments list  (corresponds to `Lists/Comments`by default)

The same field could be created via UI as demonstrated on picture below

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, yes i know how it works i use the Lookup Column ( Count related) in other lists as well in SP2010, but problem with the SP 2010 Blog is that this Column "# Comments" is somehow locked for editing may becaz it is a default column like TITEL. when i go in Column properties i see only the Name and type of Column, thats it, nothing to edit as we do in normal column. are you suggesting that i should rename existing column as "xxxxx" and create a new one with same attributes? but then how is it going to affect in blog xsl to show number of comments not from old but new column